# whats wrong in it cause error is Target class [Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Route::resource('admin/user', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class);

whats wrong in it cause error is  Target class [Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController] does not exist.

Comment: Check controller's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Laravel introduce us a different way to write route

In old version it was

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
```

In Latest version

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController; //namespace

Route::get('/',[UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score -1):

`Route::resource('admin/user', Admin\UserController::class);`